# Give current year as alias in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am selecting name field from a table and I want to give alias to the name field as current year like `SELECT name AS 'current_year' FROM 'places'` . `current_year` should be like `2014` . Is it possible ?

Comment: show the table structure and some sample data.

Comment: what you want on your result?

Comment: I just want to change alias

Comment: you want your sql "name" become "current year"?

Comment: yes like 2014 for now

Comment: you want dynamic to change sql "name"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's definitely possible, but you have to use a prepared statement:

```
SET @current_year = YEAR(CURDATE());

SET @s = CONCAT('SELECT name AS \'', @current_year, '\' FROM places');

PREPARE stmt FROM @s;

EXECUTE stmt;
```

DEMO @ [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4bd57/1)

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible.

Use this

```
SET @s = CONCAT( 'SELECT name AS \'', YEAR( CURDATE( ) ) , '\' FROM places' ) ;
PREPARE stmt FROM @s ;
EXECUTE stmt;
```